# How to configure hbase in spark?

Tags: hbase, apache-spark

What are the steps to connect spark to hbase?

I have the master addresses for both. Do I just add the hbase address into spark classpath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This post about connecting Spark With HBase should be helpful: http://www.vidyasource.com/blog/Programming/Scala/Java/Data/Hadoop/Analytics/2014/01/25/lighting-a-spark-with-hbase

> Do I just add the hbase address into spark classpath?

No. Actually, you should put the hbase configuraion files in the spark classpath. If not, you should set them in your codes, such as:

```
    Configuration hConf = HBaseConfiguration.create(conf);
    hConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "PDHadoop1.corp.CompanyName.com,PDHadoop2.corp.CompanyName.com");
    hConf.setInt("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", 10000);
```

Comment: can you tell me how to put hbase configuration files on spark classpath? is it like this - export SPARK_CLASSPATH = /path/to/hbase/conf ?

Comment: Yes. But it's only used in the driver. You can read the post above. It read hbase-site.xml in the codes.

Comment: thanks! But now I get an error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.getInputStream(Ljava/net/Socket;)Ljava/io/InputStream;
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.setupIOstreams(HBaseClient.java:437)

Comment: Looks your hbase client library is not compatible with your hadoop. You may need to use a compatible hbase for your hadoop.

Comment: do you know how to find which version of hbase is compatible with which version of hadoop?

Comment: You can check the version of your hbase cluster. Since it can run in your hadoop cluster, its version should be fine.