# File not found Exception using Spark-submit

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am running a job using spark on yarn. I have provided the link to the directory of plugins, however the exception displayed is shown below:

```
Exception: couldn't find:file:/home/centos/vopEngine1_2/lib/plugins/ANNIE/
    at gate.creole.CreoleRegisterImpl.registerDirectories(CreoleRegisterImpl.java:282)
    at gate.creole.CreoleRegisterImpl.registerDirectories(CreoleRegisterImpl.java:317)
    at com.scryAnalytics.NLPGeneric.GateGenericNLP.<init>(GateGenericNLP.java:47)
    at com.scryAnalytics.vopEngine.NlpProcessing$$anonfun$5.apply(NlpProcessing.scala:95)
    at com.scryAnalytics.vopEngine.NlpProcessing$$anonfun$5.apply(NlpProcessing.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am calling a wrapper **NLPGeneric.java** which uses the directory for its usage. This wrapper is called from a spark-scala code **NLPProcessing.scala**

NLPGeneric.java

```
package com.scryAnalytics.NLPGeneric;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import gate.Annotation;
import gate.AnnotationSet;
import gate.Corpus;
import gate.Document;
import gate.Factory;
import gate.FeatureMap;
import gate.Gate;
import gate.Resource;
import gate.creole.ExecutionException;
import gate.creole.POSTagger;
import gate.creole.ResourceInstantiationException;
import gate.creole.SerialAnalyserController;
import gate.util.GateException;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.scryAnalytics.NLPGeneric.DAO.GateAnnotation;
import com.scryAnalytics.NLPGeneric.DAO.Output;

public class GateGenericNLP {

static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GateGenericNLP.class.getName());
private SerialAnalyserController applicationPipeline;
private Corpus corpus;
private List<NLPEntities> entitiesToGenerate;

public GateGenericNLP(String pluginHome, List<NLPEntities> entities)
        throws GateException, MalformedURLException {

     System.out.println("Initializing .....");
     entitiesToGenerate = entities;
     if (!Gate.isInitialised()) {
             Gate.runInSandbox(true);
             Gate.init();
             Gate.setPluginsHome(new File(pluginHome));
             Gate.getCreoleRegister().registerDirectories(
                             new File(Gate.getPluginsHome(), "ANNIE").toURI().toURL());
             Gate.getCreoleRegister().registerDirectories(
                             new File(Gate.getPluginsHome(), "Tools").toURI().toURL());
             Gate.getCreoleRegister().registerDirectories(
                             new File(Gate.getPluginsHome(), "Tagger_NP_Chunking")
                                             .toURI().toURL());
             Gate.getCreoleRegister().registerDirectories(
                     new File(Gate.getPluginsHome(), "Stemmer_Snowball").toURI().toURL());
     }
    applicationPipeline = (SerialAnalyserController) Factory
            .createResource("gate.creole.SerialAnalyserController");

    applicationPipeline.add((gate.LanguageAnalyser) Factory
            .createResource("gate.creole.tokeniser.DefaultTokeniser"));
    applicationPipeline.add((gate.LanguageAnalyser) Factory
            .createResource("gate.creole.splitter.SentenceSplitter"));
    applicationPipeline.add((gate.LanguageAnalyser) Factory
            .createResource("stemmer.SnowballStemmer"));

    if (entitiesToGenerate.contains(NLPEntities.POS_TAGGER)) {
        applicationPipeline
                .add((gate.LanguageAnalyser) createPOSTaggerPR());

    }

    if (entitiesToGenerate.contains(NLPEntities.VP_CHUNKER)) {
        applicationPipeline.add((gate.LanguageAnalyser) Factory
                .createResource("gate.creole.VPChunker"));

    }

    if (entitiesToGenerate.contains(NLPEntities.NP_CHUNKER)) {
        applicationPipeline.add((gate.LanguageAnalyser) Factory
                .createResource("mark.chunking.GATEWrapper"));

    }

    corpus = Factory.newCorpus("VOCP Corpus");
    applicationPipeline.setCorpus(corpus);

}

public String generateNLPEntities(String message) {

    Document doc = null;
    String resultJson = "";

    try {
        doc = Factory.newDocument(message);
        System.out.println("String Added.......");
        corpus.add(doc);
        applicationPipeline.execute();

        resultJson = prepareResultJson();
        Factory.deleteResource(doc);

    } catch (ResourceInstantiationException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        logger.debug("clearing corpus.....");
        corpus.clear();
        Factory.deleteResource(doc);
    }

    return resultJson;

}

private Resource createPOSTaggerPR() throws ResourceInstantiationException {
    FeatureMap posTaggerParams = Factory.newFeatureMap();
    posTaggerParams.put(
            POSTagger.BASE_SENTENCE_ANNOTATION_TYPE_PARAMETER_NAME,
            "Sentence");
    posTaggerParams.put(
            POSTagger.BASE_TOKEN_ANNOTATION_TYPE_PARAMETER_NAME, "Token");
    posTaggerParams.put(POSTagger.OUTPUT_ANNOTATION_TYPE_PARAMETER_NAME,
            "Token");

    Resource posTagger = Factory.createResource("gate.creole.POSTagger",
            posTaggerParams);
    return posTagger;

}

private List<GateAnnotation> getTokens() {
    List<GateAnnotation> tokens = new ArrayList<GateAnnotation>();
    Document doc = corpus.get(0);
    AnnotationSet defaultAnnSet = doc.getAnnotations();
    AnnotationSet tokenSet = defaultAnnSet.get("Token");
    for (Annotation annotation : tokenSet) {

        GateAnnotation annot = new GateAnnotation(annotation.getId(),
                annotation.getStartNode(), annotation.getEndNode(),
                annotation.getType(), annotation.getFeatures());
        annot.setAnnotatedText(gate.Utils.stringFor(doc, annotation));

        tokens.add(annot);
    }
    return tokens;
}

private List<GateAnnotation> getSpaceTokens() {
    List<GateAnnotation> spaceTokens = new ArrayList<GateAnnotation>();
    Document doc = corpus.get(0);
    AnnotationSet defaultAnnSet = doc.getAnnotations();
    AnnotationSet spaceTokenSet = defaultAnnSet.get("SpaceToken");
    for (Annotation annotation : spaceTokenSet) {
        GateAnnotation annot = new GateAnnotation(annotation.getId(),
                annotation.getStartNode(), annotation.getEndNode(),
                annotation.getType(), annotation.getFeatures());
        annot.setAnnotatedText(gate.Utils.stringFor(doc, annotation));

        spaceTokens.add(annot);
    }
    return spaceTokens;
}

private List<GateAnnotation> getSentences() {
    List<GateAnnotation> sentences = new ArrayList<GateAnnotation>();
    Document doc = corpus.get(0);
    AnnotationSet defaultAnnSet = doc.getAnnotations();
    AnnotationSet sentencesSet = defaultAnnSet.get("Sentence");
    for (Annotation annotation : sentencesSet) {
        GateAnnotation annot = new GateAnnotation(annotation.getId(),
                annotation.getStartNode(), annotation.getEndNode(),
                annotation.getType(), annotation.getFeatures());
        annot.setAnnotatedText(gate.Utils.stringFor(doc, annotation));

        sentences.add(annot);
    }
    return sentences;
}

private List<GateAnnotation> getVPChunks() {
    List<GateAnnotation> vpChunks = new ArrayList<GateAnnotation>();
    Document doc = corpus.get(0);
    AnnotationSet defaultAnnSet = doc.getAnnotations();
    AnnotationSet VGSet = defaultAnnSet.get("VG");
    for (Annotation annotation : VGSet) {
        GateAnnotation annot = new GateAnnotation(annotation.getId(),
                annotation.getStartNode(), annotation.getEndNode(),
                annotation.getType(), annotation.getFeatures());
        annot.setAnnotatedText(gate.Utils.stringFor(doc, annotation));

        vpChunks.add(annot);
    }
    return vpChunks;
}

private List<GateAnnotation> getNounChunks() {

    List<GateAnnotation> nounChunks = new ArrayList<GateAnnotation>();
    Document doc = corpus.get(0);
    AnnotationSet defaultAnnSet = doc.getAnnotations();
    AnnotationSet nounChunksSet = defaultAnnSet.get("NounChunk");
    for (Annotation annotation : nounChunksSet) {
        GateAnnotation annot = new GateAnnotation(annotation.getId(),
                annotation.getStartNode(), annotation.getEndNode(),
                annotation.getType(), annotation.getFeatures());
        annot.setAnnotatedText(gate.Utils.stringFor(doc, annotation));

        nounChunks.add(annot);
    }
    return nounChunks;
}

private List<GateAnnotation> getSplits() {

    List<GateAnnotation> splits = new ArrayList<GateAnnotation>();
    Document doc = corpus.get(0);
    AnnotationSet defaultAnnSet = doc.getAnnotations();
    AnnotationSet splitSet = defaultAnnSet.get("Split");
    for (Annotation annotation : splitSet) {
        GateAnnotation annot = new GateAnnotation(annotation.getId(),
                annotation.getStartNode(), annotation.getEndNode(),
                annotation.getType(), annotation.getFeatures());
        annot.setAnnotatedText(gate.Utils.stringFor(doc, annotation));

        splits.add(annot);
    }
    return splits;
}

private String prepareResultJson() {
    Output result = new Output();
    result.setToken(getTokens());
    result.setSpaceToken(getSpaceTokens());
    result.setSentence(getSentences());
    result.setSplit(getSplits());

    if (entitiesToGenerate.contains(NLPEntities.VP_CHUNKER)) {
        result.setVG(getVPChunks());
    }

    if (entitiesToGenerate.contains(NLPEntities.NP_CHUNKER)) {
        result.setNounChunk(getNounChunks());
    }

    String resultJson = Utility.objectToJson(result);
    return resultJson;
}

public void close() {
    Factory.deleteResource(corpus);
    Factory.deleteResource(applicationPipeline);
}
```

}

NLPProcessing.scala

```
package com.scryAnalytics.vopEngine

import java.util.Arrays
import java.util.ArrayList
import gate.util.GateException
import java.net.MalformedURLException
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{ HBaseConfiguration, HTableDescriptor, TableName }
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HConstants
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.HBaseContext
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.{ TableOutputFormat, MultiTableOutputFormat }
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue.Type
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put
import com.scryAnalytics.NLPGeneric.NLPEntities
import com.vocp.ner.main.GateNERImpl
import com.scryAnalytics.NLPGeneric._
import java.util.ArrayList
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.{ SparkContext, SparkConf }
import org.apache.log4j.{ Level, Logger }
import com.scryAnalytics.vopEngine.DAO.{ GateNERDAO, GenericNLPDAO, NLPEntitiesDAO }
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable
import com.scryAnalytics.vopEngine.Configuration.VocpConfiguration
import com.scryAnalytics.vopEngine.Configuration.VOCPConstants

class NLPProcessingLog {
  var log: Logger = Logger.getLogger(classOf[NLPProcessingLog])
  log.info("Logger Initialized .....")
}

object NlpProcessing {

  val logger = new NLPProcessingLog

  @throws(classOf[Exception])
  def nlpAnnotationExtraction(conf: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration, batchString: String): Int = {

    logger.log.info("In Main Object..")

    //Initializing Spark Context 
    val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("NLPAnnotationController").setMaster("local"))

    val batchId =
      if (batchString == "newbatch")
        java.lang.Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis())
      else batchString

    conf.set("batchId", batchId)

    val inputCfs = Arrays.asList(conf.get(VOCPConstants.INPUTCOLUMNFAMILIES).split(","): _*)

    try {

      conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, conf.get(VOCPConstants.INPUTTABLE))
      conf.set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, conf.get(VOCPConstants.OUTPUTTABLE))

      val job: Job = Job.getInstance(conf, "NLPAnnotationJob")
      job.getConfiguration().set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, conf.get(VOCPConstants.OUTPUTTABLE))
      job.setOutputFormatClass(classOf[MultiTableOutputFormat])

      val admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf)
      if (!admin.isTableAvailable(conf.get(VOCPConstants.OUTPUTTABLE))) {
        val tableDesc = new HTableDescriptor(TableName.valueOf(conf.get(VOCPConstants.OUTPUTTABLE)))
        admin.createTable(tableDesc)
      }

      val hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[TableInputFormat],
        classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable],
        classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result])

      val processedFilteredRDD = hBaseRDD.map(x => x._2).filter { result =>
        val flag = Bytes.toString(result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("f"),
          Bytes.toBytes("is_processed")))
        (flag == null) || (flag == 0)
      }

      println(processedFilteredRDD.count())
      val messageRDD = processedFilteredRDD.filter { x => x != null }.map { result =>
        val message = Bytes.toString(result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("p"),
          Bytes.toBytes("message")))
        (Bytes.toString(result.getRow()), message)

      }

      println("Number of partitions " + messageRDD.getNumPartitions)

      val pluginHome = conf.get(VOCPConstants.GATE_PLUGIN_ARCHIVE)
      val requiredNLPEntities = new ArrayList[NLPEntities]()
      requiredNLPEntities.add(NLPEntities.POS_TAGGER)
      requiredNLPEntities.add(NLPEntities.VP_CHUNKER)
      requiredNLPEntities.add(NLPEntities.NP_CHUNKER)

      val nlpGenericRDD = messageRDD.mapPartitions { iter =>
        val nlpModule = new GateGenericNLP(pluginHome, requiredNLPEntities)
        iter.map { x =>
          val nlpGenericJson = nlpModule.generateNLPEntities(x._2)
          val genericNLPObject = Utility.jsonToGenericNLP(nlpGenericJson)
          (x._1, x._2, genericNLPObject)

        }
      }

      val requiredNEREntities = new ArrayList[String]()
      requiredNEREntities.add("DRUG")
      requiredNEREntities.add("SE")
      requiredNEREntities.add("REG")
      requiredNEREntities.add("ALT_THERAPY")
      requiredNEREntities.add("ALT_DRUG")

      val nlpRDD = nlpGenericRDD.mapPartitions { iter =>
        val nerModule = new GateNERImpl(pluginHome, requiredNEREntities)
        iter.map { x =>
          val nerJson = nerModule.generateNER(x._2, Utility.objectToJson(x._3))
          val nerJsonObject = Utility.jsonToGateNer(nerJson)

          val nlpEntities: NLPEntitiesDAO = new NLPEntitiesDAO
          nlpEntities.setToken(x._3.getToken())
          nlpEntities.setSpaceToken(x._3.getSpaceToken())
          nlpEntities.setSentence(x._3.getSentence())
          nlpEntities.setSplit(x._3.getSplit())
          nlpEntities.setVG(x._3.getVG)
          nlpEntities.setNounChunk(x._3.getNounChunk)

          nlpEntities.setDRUG(nerJsonObject.getDRUG())
          nlpEntities.setREG(nerJsonObject.getREG())
          nlpEntities.setSE(nerJsonObject.getSE())
          nlpEntities.setALT_DRUG(nerJsonObject.getALT_DRUG())
          nlpEntities.setALT_THERAPY(nerJsonObject.getALT_THERAPY())
          (x._1, nlpEntities)
        }
      }

      //outputRDD.foreach(println)

      val newRDD = nlpRDD.map { k => convertToPut(k) }
      newRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(job.getConfiguration())
      return 0

    } catch {
      case e: MalformedURLException => {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return 1
      }
      case e: GateException =>
        {
          e.printStackTrace()
          return 1
        }

    }
  }

  def convertToPut(genericNlpWithRowKey: (String, NLPEntitiesDAO)): (ImmutableBytesWritable, Put) = {
    val rowkey = genericNlpWithRowKey._1
    val genericNLP = genericNlpWithRowKey._2
    val put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(rowkey))
    val genCFDataBytes = Bytes.toBytes("gen")
    val nerCFDataBytes = Bytes.toBytes("ner")
    val flagCFDataBytes = Bytes.toBytes("f")

    put.add(genCFDataBytes, Bytes.toBytes("token"),
      Bytes.toBytes(Utility.objectToJson((genericNLP.getToken()))));
    put.add(genCFDataBytes, Bytes.toBytes("spaceToken"),
      Bytes.toBytes(Utility.objectToJson((genericNLP.getSpaceToken()))));
    put.add(genCFDataBytes, Bytes.toBytes("sentence"),
      Bytes.toBytes(Utility.objectToJson((genericNLP.getSentence()))));
    put.add(genCFDataBytes, Bytes.toBytes("verbGroup"),
      Bytes.toBytes(Utility.objectToJson((genericNLP.getVG()))));
    put.add(genCFDataBytes, Bytes.toBytes("split"),
      Bytes.toBytes(Utility.objectToJson((genericNLP.getSplit()))));
    put.add(genCFDataBytes, Bytes.toBytes("nounChunk"),
      Bytes.toBytes(Utility.objectToJson((genericNLP.getNounChunk()))));

    put.add(nerCFDataBytes, Bytes.toBytes("drug"),
      Bytes.toBytes(Utility.objectToJson((genericNLP.getDRUG()))))
    put.add(nerCFDataBytes, Bytes.toBytes("sideEffect"),
      Bytes.toBytes(Utility.objectToJson((genericNLP.getSE()))))
    put.add(nerCFDataBytes, Bytes.toBytes("regimen"),
      Bytes.toBytes(Utility.objectToJson((genericNLP.getREG()))))
    put.add(nerCFDataBytes, Bytes.toBytes("altTherapy"),
      Bytes.toBytes(Utility.objectToJson((genericNLP.getALT_THERAPY()))))
    put.add(nerCFDataBytes, Bytes.toBytes("altDrug"),
      Bytes.toBytes(Utility.objectToJson((genericNLP.getALT_DRUG()))))

    put.add(flagCFDataBytes, Bytes.toBytes("is_processed"),
      Bytes.toBytes("1"))
    put.add(flagCFDataBytes, Bytes.toBytes("dStatus"),
      Bytes.toBytes("0"))
    put.add(flagCFDataBytes, Bytes.toBytes("rStatus"),
      Bytes.toBytes("0"))
    put.add(flagCFDataBytes, Bytes.toBytes("adStatus"),
      Bytes.toBytes("0"))
    put.add(flagCFDataBytes, Bytes.toBytes("atStatus"),
      Bytes.toBytes("0"))

    (new ImmutableBytesWritable(Bytes.toBytes(rowkey)), put)

  }

  def pipeLineExecute(args: Array[String]): Int = {

    var batchString = ""
    val usage = "Usage: NLPAnnotationController" + " -inputTable tableName -outputTable tableName" +
      " -batchId batchId / -newbatch \n"
    if (args.length == 0) {
      System.err.println(usage)
      return -1
    }

    val conf = VocpConfiguration.create
    for (i <- 0 until args.length by 2) {
      if ("-inputTable" == args(i)) {
        conf.set(VOCPConstants.INPUTTABLE, args(i + 1))
      } else if ("-outputTable" == args(i)) {
        conf.set(VOCPConstants.OUTPUTTABLE, args(i + 1))
      } else if ("-batchId" == args(i)) {
        batchString = args(i)
      } else if ("-newbatch" == args(i)) {
        batchString = "newbatch"
      } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("arg " + args(i) + " not recognized")
      }
    }
    val result = nlpAnnotationExtraction(conf, batchString)
    result

  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val res = pipeLineExecute(args)
    System.exit(res)
  }

}
```

I ran the code using the command

```
spark-submit --driver-memory 8g --executor-memory 4g --master yarn --deploy-mode client --name NLPEntitiesGeneration --conf "spark.app.id=NLPEntitiesGeneration" target/vopEngine-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -inputTable parseddata_sample -outputTable parseddata_sample -newbatch
```

The directory /home/centos/vopEngine1_2/lib/plugins/ANNIE/ exists. What could be the possible reason for the exception?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**:- The file not found exception went away after copying the plugins folder to /tmp. However, new exception pops up showing the following details.

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 1 action: 9e941de5-84a7-43f4-9c8e-8c859976d9e1: 1 time, 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess$BatchErrors.makeException(AsyncProcess.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess$BatchErrors.access$1800(AsyncProcess.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.waitForAllPreviousOpsAndReset(AsyncProcess.java:1766)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.backgroundFlushCommits(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.mutate(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.mutate(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.MultiTableOutputFormat$MultiTableRecordWriter.write(MultiTableOutputFormat.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.MultiTableOutputFormat$MultiTableRecordWriter.write(MultiTableOutputFormat.java:76)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$4.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1113)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1111)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1251)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1119)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1091)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Suppressed: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 1 action: 9ca384fc-580c-4198-985c-6acc2af5f404: 1 time, 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess$BatchErrors.makeException(AsyncProcess.java:247)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess$BatchErrors.access$1800(AsyncProcess.java:227)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.waitForAllPreviousOpsAndReset(AsyncProcess.java:1766)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.backgroundFlushCommits(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:240)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.close(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.MultiTableOutputFormat$MultiTableRecordWriter.close(MultiTableOutputFormat.java:123)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$5.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1120)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1260)
        ... 8 more
```

yarn logs shows the following error:

```
ERROR client.AsyncProcess: Failed to get region location 
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableNotFoundException: 9e941de5-84a7-43f4-9c8e-8c859976d9e1
```

Comment: where is `--class com.scryAnalytics.vopEngine.NLPProcessingLog` in your spark-submit command

Comment: I have mentioned it in my pom file.

Answer (score 0):

use this path : 
file:///home/centos/vopEngine1_2/lib/plugins/ANNIE/

Comment: The error (this time new) occurs:
 gate.util.GateException: couldn't find:file:/mnt/yarn/nm/usercache/centos/appcache/application_1480573656109_0046/container_1480573656109_0046_01_000002/file:/home/centos/vopEngine1_2/lib/plugins/ANNIE/

Comment: what is this address ? I suggest you put all file address in /tmp path and put all file in /tmp.

Comment: I guess yarn creates a temporary folder in its path. However it doesn't find the ANNIE directory.

Comment: @wadhwasahil config that to /tmp. because it need access to write or create file or you can change access of your file to found it's work or not.

Comment: you mean copy to `/tmp`?  How will this solve the problem?

Comment: @wadhwasahil if spark need input file you can copy that to /tmp path and give it to spark. also run spark from /tmp path in other word first you go to /tmp path and then execute spark-submit .

Comment: @wadhwasahil can you set empty path ? I don't know what is path?

Comment: previous Exception goes but new one occurs
`Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, ip-172-31-5-122.us-west-2.compute.internal): org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 1 action: 9e941de5-84a7-43f4-9c8e-8c859976d9e1: 1 time, 
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess$BatchErrors.makeException(AsyncProcess.java:247)

`

Comment: @wadhwasahil first how is it gone ? second you must create new thread for new error or update question. third you must write cause error also.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: @wadhwasahil I think you can't connect to Hbase. you must set zookepper configuration for hbase and also namenode and ports.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: @wadhwasahil search and see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25652359/how-to-configure-hbase-in-spark

Comment: Actually problem lies in writing to hbase via `saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset`, as I can read the data from hbase